# Need to alternate styling on sections based on Graphql query Reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, graphql

I apologize if this is a duplicate question, having a hard time finding an answer.

I am wanting to alternate between styling on my sections in my reactJS application based on a Graphql query. The sections alternate between a picture on the left with text on the right and then the opposite on the section below it. Right now I am hard coding the new sections targeting the array item I want.

**End Goal**: Any post I publish into Graphcms automatically adds a new section with the proper styling.

Below is the code for the page as well as a picture of how it looks on the site. Any guidance is much appreciated.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { request } from 'graphql-request';



export default function Ourwork() {


    const [works, setWorks] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)


    useEffect(() => {

         

      const fetchWorks = async () => {

        const {portfolios} = await request(
          `https://api-us-east-1.graphcms.com/v2/${process.env.REACT_APP_GraphCMSKey}/master`,
          `
         {
            portfolios(stage: PUBLISHED, locales: [en]) {
                title
                description
                image {
                  url
                }
                link
              }
         }
      `
        )
         setWorks(portfolios);
        setLoading(false);
      };
  
      fetchWorks();
      
    }, []);


    if (loading) {
        return <div className="App">Loading...</div>;
      }
 






    return (
    <div>
        <section className="banner our-work bg-gray">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row work-1">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <figure className="hover-overlay ripple ripple-surface ripple-surface-light">
                            <img src={works[0].image.url} alt="portfolio 1"/>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <div className="box">
                            <h4> {works[0].title} </h4>
                            <p>{works[0].description}</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a target="_blank" href={works[0].link} rel="noreferrer">View Project</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section className="banner our-work">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row work-2">
                    <div className="col-md-6 order-md-1 order-2">
                        <div className="box ">
                            <h4>{works[1].title}</h4>
                            <p>{works[1].description}</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a target="_blank" href={works[1].link} rel="noreferrer">View Project</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6 order-md-2 order-1">
                        <figure className="hover-overlay ripple ripple-surface ripple-surface-light">
                            <img src={works[1].image.url} alt="portfolio 2" />
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section className="banner our-work bg-gray mb-0">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row work-3">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <figure className="hover-overlay ripple ripple-surface ripple-surface-light">
                            <img src={works[4].image.url} alt="portfolio 3" />
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <div className="box">
                            <h4>{works[4].title}</h4>
                            <p>{works[4].description}</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a target="_blank" href={works[4].link} rel="noreferrer">View Project</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section className="banner our-work">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row work-2">
                    <div className="col-md-6 order-md-1 order-2">
                        <div className="box ">
                            <h4>{works[3].title}</h4>
                            <p>{works[3].description}</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a target="_blank" href={works[3].link} rel="noreferrer">View Project</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6 order-md-2 order-1">
                        <figure className="hover-overlay ripple ripple-surface ripple-surface-light">
                            <img src={works[3].image.url} alt="portfolio 2" />
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section className="banner our-work bg-gray mb-0">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row work-3">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <figure className="hover-overlay ripple ripple-surface ripple-surface-light">
                            <img src={works[2].image.url} alt="portfolio 3" />
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <div className="box">
                            <h4>{works[2].title}</h4>
                            <p>{works[2].description}</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a target="_blank" href={works[2].link} rel="noreferrer">View Project</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    );
  }
```

[image: Stlying]

Comment: If it's repeating the same thing over and over again, why not just make it return a function that will loop through the array and if array[i] n % 2 == 0 (to see if it's even) and add the class to it to make it appear on right side

Ideally you don't want to use things like this works[4].title. it should be a for loop. Because what if one day you have like 100s of results in the array and you would need to copy paste the same code but change works[75].title

Comment: Thats an interesting thought, could you post a code example using my code?

Comment: Create a "left" and "right" or (odd and even) components to represent those rows. Then call `.map(item, index)` on your results, if index is even (`index % 2 === 0`) return "<Left>" with props from the data, else return "<Right>" with the props.

Answer (score 0):

To add more to my comment, i see you set the [works] array.

you can try something like this. I'm sure there are other better ways of doing it but this is quick

```
var htmlToReturn = '';
works.forEach((element, index) => {
  htmlToReturn += `
    <section className="banner our-work bg-gray">
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row work-1">
                <div className="col-md-6 ${index % 2 === 0 ? 'put to right side' : 'put to left side'}">
                    <figure className="hover-overlay ripple ripple-surface ripple-surface-light">
                        <img src={element.image.url} alt="portfolio 1"/>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div className="box">
                        <h4>${element.title} </h4>
                        <p>${element.description}</p>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a target="_blank" href=${element.link} rel="noreferrer">View Project</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

   ` 
})
return (
<div>
{htmlToReturn}
</div>

)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am going to test this function out!